# Embedding flex app in ASP.NET page (aspx)

Tags: html, apache-flex

I am making a flex app to embed in my ASP.NET portfolio. What is the best way to embed the .swf file into the HTML of the .aspx page?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what's meant by the best way, the easiest way to me is the "classic" way:

```
<OBJECT classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000" codebase="http://download.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=6,0,0,0" WIDTH="320" HEIGHT="240" id="Yourfilename" ALIGN="">
 <PARAM NAME=movie VALUE="Yourfilename.swf">
 <PARAM NAME=quality VALUE=high>
 <EMBED src="Yourfilename.swf" quality=high WIDTH="320" HEIGHT="240" NAME="Yourfilename" ALIGN="" TYPE="application/x-shockwave-flash" PLUGINSPAGE="http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer"></EMBED>
</OBJECT>
```

You might also just want to swap out the HTML code and JavaScript include files that get created by Flex Builder, in the html-template folder.

Answer (score 0):

One way is by using the [swfobject](http://code.google.com/p/swfobject/) library